# Post pipe no hace la petición en angular

Tags: angular, api, pipe

Resulta que quiero mandar una petición a un login para iniciar sesión, pero a la hora de mandarla, no hace absolutamente nada, ya comprobé la sintaxis. No sé qué anda mal. Tampoco me bota ningún error en la consola, se me hace muy extraño y llevo bastante tiempo estancado en esto.

```
login(model: LoginModel): Observable<AuthModel> {
    this.loggedIn = true;
    const email = model.email;
    const password = model.password;
    return this.http
      .post<AuthModel>(this.urlLogin, { email, password })
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          const data: AuthModel = {
            id: res._id,
            fullName: res.fullName,
            email: res.email,
            accessToken: res.token,
            refreshToken: res.refreshToken
          };
          this.toastr.success("Ingreso completado");
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
          this.setCredencials(data);
          return data;
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          const data: AuthModel = {
            id: '',
            fullName: '',
            email: '',
            accessToken: '',
            refreshToken: ''
          };
          this.toastr.error(err.response.data.message);
          return of(data);
        })
      );
  }
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar como llamas a la función login(model)

Comment: ```loginByAuth() {
        if (this.loginForm.valid) {
            this.isAuthLoading = true;
            this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value);
            this.isAuthLoading = false;
        } else {
            this.toastr.error('Formulario no válido');
        }
    }``` Esta es la que se hace desde el módulo, pero igual ya comprobé que los datos de usuario y contraseña pasan al otro lado, el problema es al hacer la petición post.

Comment: realmente el tema que veo es que, no estás ejecutando el proceso. Prueba hacer lo siguiente: this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(resp => console.log(resp)); Creo que el problema está en que declaras en el servicio la petición pero en el componente no estás suscribiendola para que se pueda ejecutar.

Comment: Hombre, muchas gracias, es que soy algo nuevo en este tema, realmente era una bobada.

Comment: Sería bueno que marcaras la respuesta como aceptada, si esta te sirvió. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

teniendo presente lo que te sugerí hacer. Te lo dejo pasmado por este medio y con unas cuantas recomendaciones.

Por lo general en los Servicios se deja el llamado a los http que requerimos, pero recuerda que allí solo se declaran los métodos.

Intenta desligar la lógica que deseas implementar según la respuesta obtenida cuando consumas tus servicios. Para ellos deberías implementar la lógica en el componente y no en tus servicios.

Ejemplo del Service

```js
login(model: LoginModel): Observable < AuthModel > {
  this.loggedIn = true;
  const email = model.email;
  const password = model.password;
  return this.http.post<AuthModel>(this.urlLogin, { email, password })
    .pipe(map(res => res, err => err));
}
```

Por el lado del componente que le llama deberías tener lo que hiciste en tu servicio.

Ejemplo del Component con subscribe

```js
loginByAuth() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    this.isAuthLoading = true;
    this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(res => {
      const data: AuthModel = {
        id: res._id,
        fullName: res.fullName,
        email: this.loginForm.value.email,
        accessToken: res.token,
        refreshToken: res.refreshToken
      };
      this.toastr.success("Ingreso completado");
      this.setCredencials(data);
      this.isAuthLoading = false;
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }, err => {
      this.toastr.error(err.message);
      this.isAuthLoading = false;
    });
  } else {
    this.toastr.error('Formulario no válido');
  }
}
```

Otor ejemplo del Component con Promise

```js
loginByAuth() {
  if (this.loginForm.valid) {
    this.isAuthLoading = true;
    this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value)..toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        const data: AuthModel = {
          id: res._id,
          fullName: res.fullName,
          email: this.loginForm.value.email,
          accessToken: res.token,
          refreshToken: res.refreshToken
        };
        this.toastr.success("Ingreso completado");
        this.setCredencials(data);
        this.isAuthLoading = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }).cacth(err => {
        this.toastr.error(err.message);
        this.isAuthLoading = false;
      });
  } else {
    this.toastr.error('Formulario no válido');
  }
}
```

Cualquiera de las dos formas que te expongo en el Component te sirven con el servicio que te puse de ejemplo.

Saludos, espero te sirva.